# Adding PFUsers to a tableView only loads one user?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I Am Querying a set of PFUsers from Parses backend datebase. I then want to place those users into a TableView, although for some reason it is only loading this first user of the query for some reason. Can somebody help, code:

```
struct UserMatches {

    var finalMatchesName : String
    var finalMatchesAge : Int
    var finalMatchesLocation : PFGeoPoint
    var finalMatchesImage : NSData
}

        class Matches: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

            var user = PFUser.currentUser()

            var tableView = UITableView()

            var userMatches = [UserMatches]()

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                matchedUsers()
                createTableView()

            }

            func createTableView() {

                tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 10)
                tableView.dataSource = self
                tableView.delegate = self
                tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return self.userMatches.count

        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            let userDetails = self.userMatches[indexPath.row]

            //Name
            var nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15, 3, cell.frame.width / 1.2, cell.frame.height / 2))
            nameLabel.font = UIFont(name: Font.FuturaBlack, size: 20)
            nameLabel.numberOfLines = 1
            nameLabel.text = userDetails.finalMatchesName
            nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

            //Distance
            var distanceLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15, nameLabel.frame.height + 3, cell.frame.width / 1.2, cell.frame.height / 3))
            distanceLabel.font = UIFont(name: Font.FuturaMedium, size: 16)
            distanceLabel.numberOfLines = 1
            distanceLabel.text = "0.25 Miles Away"
            distanceLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            distanceLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

            //image
            var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + cell.frame.width - cell.frame.height - 5, 5, cell.frame.height - 10, cell.frame.height - 10))
            let image = UIImage(named: "hot.png")
            var images = UIImage(data: userDetails.finalMatchesImage)
            imageView.image = images
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill


            cell.addSubview(imageView)
            cell.addSubview(distanceLabel)
            cell.addSubview(nameLabel)

            return cell
        }

func matchedUsers() {

            //Query Matches
            var matchesIdQuery = PFUser.query()
            matchesIdQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: user.objectId)
            if var result = matchesIdQuery.getFirstObject() {

            let matchesId = result["matches"] as [String]

                let matchesQuery = PFUser.query()
                matchesQuery.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: matchesId)
                let finalResult = matchesQuery.findObjects()
                    if finalResult.count > 0 {

                        for finalMatches in finalResult {

                            let matchesImageFile = finalMatches["image"] as PFFile
                            if let finalMatchesImageFile = matchesImageFile.getData() {

                                println(finalMatches.count) //Prints 2

                                self.userMatches = [UserMatches(finalMatchesName: finalMatches.username, finalMatchesAge: finalMatches["age"] as Int, finalMatchesLocation: finalMatches["location"] as PFGeoPoint, finalMatchesImage: finalMatchesImageFile)]

                                println(self.userMatches.count) //Prints 1

                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

}

The problem is coming where I am trying to load the `UserMatches` inside the `matchedUsers` function, although it is only loading one user, not all of the users I have queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're assigning a single value to your array in your loop (in `matchedUsers()`) instead of appending to it.

Try replacing:

```
self.userMatches = [UserMatches(finalMatchesName: finalMatches.username, finalMatchesAge: finalMatches["age"] as Int, finalMatchesLocation: finalMatches["location"] as PFGeoPoint, finalMatchesImage: finalMatchesImageFile)]
```

with:

```
self.userMatches.append(UserMatches(finalMatchesName: finalMatches.username, finalMatchesAge: finalMatches["age"] as Int, finalMatchesLocation: finalMatches["location"] as PFGeoPoint, finalMatchesImage: finalMatchesImageFile))
```

Comment: Yes! Brilliant! I new I was close, thank you very much